# Non Deterministic Function

Tags: sql-server

sql server is telling me that this function is non deterministic.  I am confused because given date x it will always return the same.

```
DATEADD(d, 13 - DATEDIFF(d, '9/23/10', serviceDate) % 14, serviceDate)
```

Comment: What is `date x`? I only see d and h

Comment: h.serviceDate is date x

Comment: Can you show us the whole statement/query? You are probably doing something such as assigning different values to one place.

Comment: i was trying to make this a calculated function.  thats where it said that it was non deterministic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  CONVERT(DATE,  DATEADD(d, 13 - DATEDIFF(d, CONVERT(DATE, '9/23/10',101), serviceDate) % 14, serviceDate),101)
```

> When you refer to date data type string literals in indexed computed
>   columns in SQL Server, we recommend that you explicitly convert the
>   literal to the date type that you want by using a deterministic date
>   format style. For a list of the date format styles that are
>   deterministic, see CAST and CONVERT. Expressions that involve implicit
>   conversion of character strings to date data types are considered
>   nondeterministic, unless the database compatibility level is set to 80
>   or earlier. This is because the results depend on the LANGUAGE and
>   DATEFORMAT settings of the server session. For example, the results of
>   the expression CONVERT (datetime, '30 listopad 1996', 113) depend on
>   the LANGUAGE setting because the string '30 listopad 1996' means
>   different months in different languages. Similarly, in the expression
>   DATEADD(mm,3,'2000-12-01'), the Database Engine interprets the string
>   '2000-12-01' based on the DATEFORMAT setting.
>
> CAST
>
> Deterministic unless used with datetime, smalldatetime, or
>   sql_variant.
>
> CONVERT
>
> Deterministic unless one of these conditions exists:
>
> ...
>
> Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source
>   or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is
>   specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a
>   constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are
>   nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100
>   are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.